# How to achieve 3-column layout with image and text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, layout

I'm trying to create a 3-column layout in Flutter where each column contains an image centred above a text label.  I'd like the columns to be evenly spaced across the screen.

**Visuals:**

I want to achieve this:

[image]

For now, I got this:

[image]

**Code:**

```
class LogIn extends StatefulWidget {
  const LogIn({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LogIn> createState() => _LogInState();
}

class _LogInState extends State<LogIn> {
  bool isAPIcallProcess = false;
  bool hidePassword = true;
  GlobalKey<FormState> globalFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String? username;
  String? password;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffF24004),
        body: Center(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                left: 20,
                  right: 20,
                  top: 100,
                  child: Image.asset(
                      "lib/img/pomodoro.png",
                  width: 250,
                  height: 250,))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So, **how can I achieve the 3 columns?** I tried to make another stateful widget but I don't know why but it doesn't work, I think is because the main design is in this MaterialApp widget.

Comment: By columns, did you mean Rows?  or is your phone on its side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better if you separate material-app context in further use case. Also try using `Align` widget for dynamic placement.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: const Color(0xffF24004),
    body: LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) => Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: const Alignment(0, -.75),
            child: Container(
              width: constraints.maxWidth * .8, //image size
              height: constraints.maxWidth * .8,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            // Image.asset(
            //   "lib/img/pomodoro.png",
            //   width: 250,
            //   height: 250,
            // ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                ...List.generate(
                  3,
                  (index) => Container(
                    width: constraints.maxWidth,
                    height: constraints.maxHeight * .1,
                    color: index.isEven ? Colors.deepPurple : Colors.amber,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]
More about [`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)